# Regex for detect specified url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to filter url's like bartender/profili/20/friends using preg_match.

Regex:

```
/^\/bartender\/profili\/d+\/friends/
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slash in front of `d+` (and have selected a badly readable delimiter for this situation). Try this:

`#^\/bartender\/profili\/\d+\/friends#`

Comment: I think you don't need to escape forward slash if you use `#` as a delimiter. No?

Comment: @Berry Langerak That'd mean I've made about a zilion bugs so far.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to capture the \d+? If so, enclose them in ( ), that should fix it. Also, if you're regex uses /, I'd suggest using a different delimiter, less escaping that way:

```
<?php
preg_match( 
    '~^/bartender/profili/(\d+)/friends~', 
    '/bartender/profili/20/friends', 
    $matches 
);

var_dump( $matches );
```

*Addendum*: and - like everyone already mentioned - you indeed forgot the \ in front of the d+, but that was easy to overlook if you have to escape every / ;)

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to escape `\d+`

```
/^\/bartender\/profili\/\d+\/friends/
```

Comment: @genesis; no, he didn't, please read more carefully before a downvote. Upvoting the answer.

Comment: @genesis, you are wrong. Look carefully. I have added an extra backslash before `d+`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a backslash before `d+`: `\d+`

Answer (score 2):

"`bartender\/profili\/[0-9]+\/friends`" also works. Here's an excellent resource for trying regular expressions: http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to escape forward slashes, but you need to escape meta-characters (like 'd' for decimal digits)

^/bartender/profili/\d+/friends/

Comment: If / is your delimiter you *do* have to escape the forward slashes. You ignored the delimiters altogether it seems.